# multiple upload menu for 1 page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to create 4 upload menus (each one only can upload one time at moment)
here's what i want to do

```
|-------------------|
| upload 1          |
|                   |
|-------------------|
|2     |3     |4    |
|------|------|-----|
```

I'm using droparea jquery plugin right now.
here if u wanna check the demo http://www.jqueryrain.com/?DcZAsxGN

the problem is. if i only have 1 upload menu, its work well.
but when i try to create 4 upload menu. it didn't work.
in example: if i wanna upload image in second menu. the image show up in first upload menu. and then i realize because its using id, so i change to class.
and then when i try to re-run my code. when i upload image in second menu. it affect to the outer upload menu. (change all image to the same like second menu)

from like this

[image]

to this

[image]

my code is like this

```
<div class="upload-photo">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="droparea" >
                <img src="http://placehold.it/200" class="file_preview" >
            </div>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept="image/*" style="display: none;" >
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <div class="droparea" >
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/200" class="file_preview" >
                </div>
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept="image/*" style="display: none;" >
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <div class="droparea" >
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/200" class="file_preview" >
                </div>
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept="image/*" style="display: none;" >
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <div class="droparea" >
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/200" class="file_preview" >
                </div>
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept="image/*" style="display: none;" >
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.droparea').droparea({
                    url: 'server.php',
                    success: function( server_return, name, uploaded_file )
                    {
                        $('.droparea').after( $('<p />').html( 'File sent: <b>' + name + '</b>' ) );

                        var oFReader = new FileReader();

                        oFReader.readAsDataURL( uploaded_file );
                        oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent)
                        {
                            $( '.file_preview' ).animate({opacity: 0}, 'slow', function(){
                                // change the image source
                                $(this).closest('.droparea')
                                    .attr('src', oFREvent.target.result).animate({opacity: 1}, 'fast')
                                    .on('load', function()
                                    {
                                        $('.statusbar').css({
                                            width: $('.droparea').outerWidth(),
                                            height: $('.droparea').outerHeight()
                                        });
                                    });

                                // remove the alert block whenever it exists.
                                $('.droparea').find('.statusbar.alert-block').fadeOut('slow', function(){ $(this).remove(); });
                            });
                        };
                    }
                });
      });
```

sorry if its dumb question, but please help me. or u guys know jquery plugin that work like this??

the first time its id="file_preview" but i change to class="preview" but its affect to all of upload menu. i try to add .closest('.droparea') in script to make it specific, but nothing change.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but, try this source.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for(var i=0;i<$('.droparea').length;i++){
            $($('.droparea')[i]).droparea({
                        url: 'server.php',
                        success: function( server_return, name, uploaded_file )
                        {
                            $(this).after( $('<p />').html( 'File sent: <b>' + name + '</b>' ) );
                            var dropArea = $(this);
                            var filePreview = $(this).parent().children('.file_preview');
                            var oFReader = new FileReader();

                            oFReader.readAsDataURL( uploaded_file );
                            oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent)
                            {
                            filePreview.animate({opacity: 0}, 'slow', function(){
                                    // change the image source
                                    dropArea
                                        .attr('src', oFREvent.target.result).animate({opacity: 1}, 'fast')
                                        .on('load', function()
                                        {
                                            $('.statusbar').css({
                                                width: dropArea.outerWidth(),
                                                height: dropArea.outerHeight()
                                            });
                                        });

                                    // remove the alert block whenever it exists.
                                    dropArea.find('.statusbar.alert-block').fadeOut('slow', function(){ $(this).remove(); });
                                });
                            };
                        }
                    });
               }
          });
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for(var i=0;i<$('.droparea').length;i++){
         $($('.droparea')[i]).droparea({
                    url: 'server.php',
                    success: function( server_return, name, uploaded_file )
                    {
                        $($('.droparea')[i]).after( $('<p />').html( 'File sent: <b>' + name + '</b>' ) );

                        var oFReader = new FileReader();

                        oFReader.readAsDataURL( uploaded_file );
                        oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent)
                        {
                            $($( '.file_preview' )[i]).animate({opacity: 0}, 'slow', function(){
                                // change the image source
                                $($('.droparea')[i])
                                    .attr('src', oFREvent.target.result).animate({opacity: 1}, 'fast')
                                    .on('load', function()
                                    {
                                        $('.statusbar').css({
                                            width: $($('.droparea')[i]).outerWidth(),
                                            height: $($('.droparea')[i]).outerHeight()
                                        });
                                    });

                                // remove the alert block whenever it exists.
                                $($('.droparea')[i]).find('.statusbar.alert-block').fadeOut('slow', function(){ $(this).remove(); });
                            });
                        };
                    }
                });
      });
```

Comment: still affect all of the the upload menu sir. do you know plugin like this.?

Comment: I modified my source. I am not sure too but.. try again.

Comment: didnt work sir. but itry the dropzone and i will let u know